# How do I communicate using an event between an iOS app and a Windows Service?

Tags: iphone, ios, service, ibaction, iboutlet

I want to be able to use a service to identify that an event occurred on the iOS app and then send a response to the iOS app based on the event.

**Here's a scenario:**

I have one button and one text field.

- If I push the button and there is NO input in the text field, that would be an 'event' that I would need to identify and send to a Windows web service.
- If the text field DOES have input and I press the button, that would be a different 'event' that would need to be identified and sent to the Windows web service.

I'm not really sure how to go about this, so I'm open to suggestions. Also, I would like this to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what I mean is, do I set some sort of boolean flag per event and then pass it to the Windows service?  I don't really know what other options I have.  I figure if I do go down that route, the more scenarios that I think up, the more cluttered my code might get when checking conditions and setting flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1:

```
NSString * myText = [self.textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];    

if (0 == [myText length]) {
  // call web service method 1:
  ...
} else {
  // call web service method 2:
  ...
}
```

option 2:

call your web service method passing it the contents of textField and let it handle the hard work, on the app side just check the web service response using an if-else and do likewise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply asking how to check whether a text field contains anything then something like this should work (textField has type UITextField):

```
NSString * myText = self.textField.text;

if (0 == [myText length]) {
  // no text, do something
  ...
} else {
  // text, do something else
  ...
}
```

However, if you are asking how to make requests to a web service from iOS then there are a number of tutorials you can check out (e.g. [MVCNetworking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html)) or have a look at a toolkit like [RESTkit](http://restkit.org/).